# Prove inequality $(1+x+y)(1+y+z)(1+z+x) \ge 9(xy+xz+yz)$

Tags: inequality

I need to prove inequality
$$(1+x+y)(1+y+z)(1+z+x) \ge 9(xy+xz+yz)$$
for nonnegative $x,y,z \ge 0$

I can do it with partitional derivates
$$f(x,y,z)=((1+x+y)(1+y+z)(1+z+x)-9(xy+xz+yz))$$
and find
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=2xy + 2xz + 2yz + z^2 + y^2 + 2x - 6y - 6z + 2$$
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=2xy + 2xz + 2yz + x^2 + z^2 + 2y - 6c - 6x + 2$$
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial c}=2xy + 2xz + 2yz + x^2 + y^2 + 2z - 6x - 6y + 2$$
minimum value of function $f$ is $f(1,1,1)=0$ that's why $(1+x+y)(1+y+z)(1+z+x) \ge 9(xy+xz+yz)$.

But I need the prove without partitional derivates. 
Any standart inequality (Inequality of arithmetic and geometric means, Cauchy–Schwarz inequality) don't help me.